# React hide textarea but writable

Tags: reactjs, text-editor

I'm making text editor from bottom up.

I want to give the illusion that users are using textarea directly.

So I think that in one big `<div/>` put `<textarea>` and `<p>` and hide textarea and show value of `<textarea>` in `<p>`.
When user click word in `<p>`, Put cursor in appropriate textarea and write word
in textarea  (`<p>` is used just to show result)

But when i give `display: hidden` for this, I cannot type anything in textarea.
How can i show illusion to user use textarea directly but not really.

```
class CodeEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    textValue: ''
    }
  }

  underline = () => {
    let textVal = this.editor;
    let Start = textVal.selectionStart;
    let End = textVal.selectionEnd;
    const oldState = this.state.textValue;
    if (oldState.substring(Start,End) !== '') {
      this.setState({textValue : oldState.substr(0,Start) + `<p style={{text-decoration-line:underline}}>` + oldState.substring(Start, End) + `</p>` + oldState.substr(End)})
    }
  };
  render() {
    const content = this.state.textValue;

    return (
      <div className={cx('text-editor')} onClick={() => 
         this.editor.focus()}>
        <textarea
          className={cx('text-input')}
          ref={ref => this.editor = ref}
          value={this.state.textValue}
          style={{display:'hidden'}}
          onChange={(event) => {
            this.setState({
              textValue:event.target.value
            });
          }} />
        <div className={cx('editor-buttons')}>
          <button onClick={this.underline}> Underline </button>
        </div>
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />
    </div>
 )};
}
export default CodeEditor;
```

Comment: You can't style the `textarea` to look like you want instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize contenteditable html5 feature:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable

Comment: Thank you!! using contenteditable is more convenient to depelove! :-)

Comment: @SangHoKim Any time! :D

Answer (score 0):

For you all looking for an answer for this, here's an approach you can take:

1) Textarea/input has a border, so hide it with `border-style: none` and hide when focus with `textarea:focus, input:focus { outline: none; }`.

2) Change the background color to be the same as parent component.

3) Done :)